Ошибка в дублировании классов зависимостей unity Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'
после добавления в проект SDK мобильной рекламы Yandex Mobile SDK при компиляции на Android выдает нижеописанную ошибку.
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class a.a.a found in modules jetified-com.android.installreferrer.installreferrer-2.2-runtime (:com.android.installreferrer.installreferrer-2.2:) and jetified-installreferrer-2.2-runtime (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.RemoteActionCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.Cancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2 found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$3 found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$NonConfigurationInstances found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ImmLeaksCleaner found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher$LifecycleOnBackPressedCancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher$OnBackPressedCancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner found in modules jetified-activity-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyThread found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ArrayRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AttrRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BinderThread found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BoolRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CallSuper found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CheckResult found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ChecksSdkIntAtLeast found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorInt found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorLong found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ContentView found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.DimenRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Dimension found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.DoNotInline found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.DrawableRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FloatRange found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FontRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FractionRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.GuardedBy found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.HalfFloat found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IdRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InspectableProperty found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InspectableProperty$EnumEntry found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InspectableProperty$FlagEntry found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InspectableProperty$ValueType found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntDef found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntRange found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntegerRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InterpolatorRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Keep found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.LayoutRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.LongDef found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.MainThread found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.MenuRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.NavigationRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.NonNull found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Nullable found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.OptIn found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-experimental-1.3.0-runtime (:androidx.annotation.annotation-experimental-1.3.0:) and jetified-annotation-experimental-1.3.0-runtime (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.PluralsRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Px found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RawRes found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresApi found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresFeature found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.1 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.1)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresOptIn found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-experimental-1.3.0-runtime (:androidx.annotation.annotation-experimental-1.3.0:) and jetified-annotation-experimental-1.3.0-runtime (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresOptIn$Level found in modules jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-experimental-1.3.0-runtime (:androidx.annotation.annotation-experimental-1.3.0:) and jetif<message truncated>

Пробовал различные методы устранения данной ошибки, найденные в открытых источниках. Например, добавил кастомные gradle и gradle properties. Убедился, что в properties есть строки: use androidx=true; use jetifier=true. Пробовал false у них ставить. Решение на данный момент так и не нашел.
Версия SDK: 7.2.0.
Версия юнити: 2022.3.40f1.
Сторонних сервисов рекламы или аналитики в проекте нет.
Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Спасибо заранее!
